# Docker-Compose: Why are my rails images having permission issues accessing MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

## Buggy Behavior

I'm using **docker-compose** in **Ubuntu 18.04** to work with some **Ruby on Rails** projects, however, every time I try to use the rails console I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:192:in `initialize': Permission denied @ dir_initialize - /usr/src/app/docker/mysql/data/performance_schema (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:192:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:192:in `watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:202:in `block in watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:202:in `block in watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:202:in `block in watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:202:in `block in watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.10/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:194:in `watch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/adapter/linux.rb:32:in `_configure'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in `block in configure'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `configure'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/listener.rb:68:in `block in <class:Listener>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/fsm.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/fsm.rb:121:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/fsm.rb:91:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/fsm.rb:57:in `transition'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/listen-3.1.5/lib/listen/listener.rb:91:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-watcher-listen-2.0.1/lib/spring/watcher/listen.rb:27:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:80:in `start_watcher'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:89:in `preload'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

**I can make the console work by** going into my bash command and **changing the permissions** of the mysql folder that stores the image by using the following command:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser docker/mysql/
```

However, doing this makes other features of rails break. For example the `rails db:reset` command throws the following error:

```
-- create_table("actions", {:force=>:cascade, :options=>"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC"})
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Can't create table 'actions' (errno: 13): CREATE TABLE `actions` (`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `workflow_id` bigint, `type` varchar(191), `settings` text, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,  INDEX `index_actions_on_type_and_workflow_id`  (`type`, `workflow_id`),  INDEX `index_actions_on_workflow_id`  (`workflow_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:214:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:213:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:212:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:26:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:288:in `create_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:363:in `create_table'
/usr/src/app/config/initializers/utf8mb4.rb:7:in `create_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:838:in `method_missing'
/usr/src/app/db/schema.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:48:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:48:in `define'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:44:in `define'
/usr/src/app/db/schema.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:233:in `load_schema'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:255:in `block in load_schema_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:304:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:254:in `load_schema_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:248:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:252:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error: Can't create table 'actions' (errno: 13)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:214:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:213:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:212:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb:26:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:288:in `create_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:363:in `create_table'
/usr/src/app/config/initializers/utf8mb4.rb:7:in `create_table'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:838:in `method_missing'
/usr/src/app/db/schema.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:48:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:48:in `define'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/schema.rb:44:in `define'
/usr/src/app/db/schema.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:233:in `load_schema'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:255:in `block in load_schema_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:304:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:303:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:254:in `load_schema_current'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:248:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:252:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/usr/src/app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I haven't found any other docker user with this problem and my peers don't have this same issue whatsoever. Granted, they use other operating systems such as **MAC-OS** or **Debian**.

Each time I need these features I have to restart the images or sometimes start from scratch rebuilding the entire docker ecosystem which is very time-consuming and annoying.

## Configuration

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    container_name: myapp_web
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      APP_IP: 174.21.0.2
      OMNIAUTH_IP: 174.21.1.5
    hostname: test.host
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 4567:4567
    links:
      - mysql
    # For using pry
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 174.21.0.2
    extra_hosts:
      - "test.host:174.21.0.2"
      - "myapp.host:174.21.0.2"

  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    container_name: myapp_mysql
    env_file: .env
    command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci]
    ports:
      - 32788:3306
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 174.21.0.4
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 174.21.1.0/16
    name: myapp_dev_net

volumes:
  gems:
```

this is my MySQL Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.6
```

## Expected Behavior

I want my docker implementation to work properly, I don't want to restart my containers every 15 minutes when I need to do some changes to the database. Any suggestions are welcome.

## Aditional Questions

Is there any reason as to why this Happens in Ubuntu 18 but not in Debian or MAC-OS? I'm an Ubuntu fan and I'd Like to fix this in Ubuntu, But if switching OS would improve my experience with docker I'd do it without question.

Comment: Why do you need this volume mount `./:/usr/src/app` in `mysql`?

Comment: @ShashankV honestly I don't know, that volume has been there since long before I came into this project. But it should be unrelated to the real issue that is causing me problems with docker-compose because everybody else that uses MAC or Debian has no problem with it. It's only me using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have two users trying to make changes to mysql directories. Maybe instead of `chown`, you could try a `chmod 777` on your directory. Maybe also the `tmpdir` used by mysql (`/tmp`, or whichever directory you can see when running `show variables like '%tmpdir%';`)

But, are you starting your ruby console from inside your container or from your ubuntu ? The only user connecting to your database should be within your mysql container. And you should connect to the database using the port binding.

You can also try to mount a volume for your data to be stored / persisted with docker: [more about volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Change your docker-compose file :

```
[file start...]
mysql:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
  container_name: myapp_mysql
  env_file: .env
  command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci]
  ports:
    - 32788:3306
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/app
# CHANGE HERE
    - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
  networks:
    net:
      ipv4_address: 174.21.0.4
[more file...]
volumes:
  gems:
# AND CHANGE HERE
  mysqldata:
```

Your mysqldata volume will be persisted between two starts of your container, and being inside the container, you should not have issues with permissions. It appears to be [the default](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

If you need to resume your current state, only the first time when switching from your current setup to a volume based setup, you can make a mysqldump, put it in the folder you are already mounting `- ./:/usr/src/app` (or any other), and restore your database from inside the container.

I have no idea why the behaviour is different with other OS. I use a volume to persist mysql data.